# jQuery: Append and prepend unclosed HTML to an element

Tags: jquery

In an application I'm creating, I am allowing the end-users to add a "Text Formatting" prefix and suffix to a jQuery countdown.
The elements for the countdown are fetched with AJAX, and inserted to DOM with jQ.

An example for these two fields can be:
Prefix: `<span style="color:blue">`
Suffix: `</span>`

What I need to do then is wrap all the code needed for the countdown between these two.
But when I try to add them, all jQuery methods I've tried (append & prepend) and PrototypeJS' `Element.insert()` will close any open tags in the prefix, rendering the suffix useless.

I even tried the following:

```
$( this ).parent().html( data['prefix'] + $( this ).parent().html() + data['suffix'] );
```

This resulted in the element being removed from the DOM tree. Also tried to locally store the innerHTML and fiddle with it before pushing it back to `.html()`.

And I can not combine those two fields together, and use `.wrap()` on it, as either of them can be a completely perfect HTML string.

```
<span class='tag'>This is a tag</span>
```

If I tried to use `.wrap()` on that, I assume the rest of my code would end up inside that.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), it's not very clear what you're after and difficult to provide a correct answer.

Comment: @maxedison made a jsfiddle that shows exactly what I want to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/xPb2a/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.wrap()`, but check first to see if it is a full tag:

var openTag = prefix.split(' ')[0].slice(1); //results in something like 'span' or 'div'
var closingTagExists = prefix.slice(prefix.length - openTag.length - 3) === '';

if(closingTagExists){
    myEl.before(prefix).after(suffix);
}else{
    myEl.wrap(prefix);
}

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xPb2a/

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time!  
It (almost) worked like a charm. In cases where you combine both cases in my initial post, a "tag" and coloring, the latter was excluded.  
http://jsfiddle.net/xPb2a/1/

Comment: That's true. But is there not enough here for you to figure out how to handle a case like that?

Comment: After staring at this for a couple of moments, leaving for a while and coming back to it, I decided that I'm overdoing this whole operation. There is a way to add text both before and after the counter already, and all I needed was a way to style the whole thing. Added a "styleHolder" wrapper around it where I only needed to write the style attribute from the AJAX response. Pretty much the same functionality, but one less field for the end-user to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You cann not insert unclosed tag with .html():

```
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5317
```

You could do somthing like this:

```
function GetCodeFromServer(){ /*...*/ return "code from server"; }

function Build(){
  var code = GetCodeFromServer();
  var $myTag = $("<span />").append(code);
  //if you want append to any container
  $("#anyDivContainer").append($myTag);
 }
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/jlrvpuma/59ts8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin:

```
$.fn.surroundWith = function( a,b ) {  

    return this.each(function() {

          var id='dummy'+$.now();

          $('<div class="'+id+'">'+a+'<span class="'+id+'"/>'+b+'</div>')
           .insertAfter(this)
            .find('span.'+id)
              .replaceWith(this)
               .end()
               .replaceWith(
                            function() {
                            return $(this).contents();
                            });

    })};
```

Instead of using wrap() it injects a fragment after the target, this fragment is build like this:

```
$(prefix+placeHolder+suffix)
```

After inserting this fragment, the placeholder-element will be replaced by the target.

You may test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/yUAVk/